# Where to find EKS master node IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

Where/How can I get the IP address of the `Master Node` in an AWS EKS cluster?

I would like to use NodePort services bound to the Master Node's IP address.

Comment: In EKS the control plane is fully managed. You do not have access to the master nodes directly.

Comment: Doesn't `kubectl cluster-info` return the Kubernetes control plane DNS name?